# openlayers map.updateSize when the width of the map changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, openlayers

when displaying a side panel, I would like the proportion of the map to be kept inside the new div width (or height). There it is simply reduced, which affects the breadth of the countries. I tried to map.updateSize without success. How can i do it ?
more details

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
   
  })/*,
   minResolution: "auto",
   maxResolution: "auto"*/
});
/*window.onresize = function(event)
{
   map.zoomOut(); map.zoomIn();
}*/
/*$('#map').on('change',function(){setTimeout(() => { this.map.updateSize(); });})*/
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("main aside").css("display","block");
  $("main section").css("width","1000px");
  $("#map").css("width","1000px")
   }); 
$("#close").click(function(){
  $("main aside").css("display","none");
  $("main section").css("width","1100px");
  $("#map").css("width","1100px")
   });
/*map.updateSize()*/
/*map.onresize = setTimeout(() => { this.map.updateSize() })*/
$(window).resize(function () {
  if (window.resizeMapUpdateTimer) {
    clearTimeout(window.resizeMapUpdateTimer)
  }
  window.resizeMapUpdateTimer= setTimeout(function () {
    // Update container size
    map.updateSize()
  }, 500)
})`var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
   
  })/*,
   minResolution: "auto",
   maxResolution: "auto"*/
});
/*window.onresize = function(event)
{
   map.zoomOut(); map.zoomIn();
}*/
/*$('#map').on('change',function(){setTimeout(() => { this.map.updateSize(); });})*/
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("main aside").css("display","block");
  $("main section").css("width","1000px");
  $("#map").css("width","1000px")
   }); 
$("#close").click(function(){
  $("main aside").css("display","none");
  $("main section").css("width","1100px");
  $("#map").css("width","1100px")
   });
/*map.updateSize()*/
/*map.onresize = setTimeout(() => { this.map.updateSize() })*/
$(window).resize(function () {
  if (window.resizeMapUpdateTimer) {
    clearTimeout(window.resizeMapUpdateTimer)
  }
  window.resizeMapUpdateTimer= setTimeout(function () {
    // Update container size
    map.updateSize()
  }, 500)
})
```

https://codepen.io/epinrap/pen/gOgwLvZ

Comment: You call `.updateSize()` when you want to redraw the map after resizing the map div (either the window or add/removing side panels in your case).  This doesn't not affect the zoom.  You need to re-zoom to match new size, probably using `.getZoomForExtent` or just `.zoomToExtent` directly

Comment: thanks for the answer
.updateSize was the solution, the question was to trigger it
and it works with when pushing buttons
setTimeout(function () {
    // Update container size
    map.updateSize()
  }, 300)

Comment: Well, glad you got it to work, but not really sure what you did, as you also stated: *I tried to map.updateSize without success*

Comment: yes, if you read my code, I tried to make this map.updatesize via the window.resize and it did not work because it does not intercept changes of the dimensions of the div. There the trigger is the action of the button

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
  window.onresize = () => {
                setTimeout(() => { 
                    this.olMap.updateSize();
                }, 500);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

map.updateSize was the solution, the question was to trigger it later
and it works when I put this in the button scripts :

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // Update container size
    map.updateSize()
  }, 300)
```